# Casting derived class to base class keeps knowledge of derived when using generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

I have a weird scenario that I can't seem to wrap my head around.  I have the following base class:

```
public class Note
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string SenderId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Which is then derived by the following class:

```
public class NoteAttachment : Note
{
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public string MD5 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I use these classes to communicate with a server, through a generic wrapper:

```
public class DataRequest<T> : DataRequest
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

public class DataRequest
{
    public string SomeField { get; set; }
    public string AnotherField { get; set; }
}
```

So I have a `NoteAttachment` sent to the method, but I need to wrap a `Note` object to send to the server.  So I have the following extension method:

```
    public static DataRequest<T> GetDataRequest<T>(this T data)
    {
        DataRequest<T> dataRequest = new DataRequest<T>
        {
            SomeField = "Some Value",
            AnotherField = "AnotherValue",
            Data = data
        };

        return dataRequest;
    }
```

Now the problem.  Calling the extension method in the following way works fine, however even though the DataRequest type is `DataRequest<Note>`, the Data field is of type `NoteAttachment`.

```
var noteAttachment = new NoteAttachment();

...

Note note = (Note)noteAttachment;

var dataRequest = note.GetDataRequest();

Debug.WriteLine(dataRequest.GetType()); //MyProject.DataRequest`1[MyProject.Note]
Debug.WriteLine(dataRequest.Data.GetType()); //MyProject.NoteAttachment <--WHY?!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Upcasting doesn't remove the underlying constructed type, hence GetType returns NoteAttachment. You may need to make your generic method covariant for this to do what you want.

Comment: If you are looking for the current type within your generic type, you want to use typeof(T) instead of GetType().  typeof(T) will return "Note" in your example, while GetType() will return the type that was used to create that object or "NoteAttachment" in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing two things: run-time type of an object and compile type of a field.

Type of `Data` field is still `Note`. You can verify for yourself with reflection. For example, the following will print "Note":

```
Console.Write(
     typeof(DataRequest<Note>).GetProperty("Data").PropertyType.Name);
```

The `Type` of the object that this field contains can be `Note` or any derived type. Assigning an object to the variable of a base class *does not* change its run-time class. And since `GetType()` returns the type of an object you get the actual derived type (`NoteAttachment`).

Comment: The issue is when sending the `DataRequest<Note>` object through WCF, it is trying to deserialize `Data` as a `NoteAttachment` type instead of a `Note` type, and failing because the endpoint is not expecting the NoteAttachment type.  How do I overcome this?

Comment: @Spankachu you probably should ask separate question about it (or significantly edit this one)... I don't think you have much control on deserialization - if serialized data have particular type it will be hard to deserialize into another type - fixing serialization side could be better, but how to do it depends on your actual code/type of serialization your have.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov 's answer fixed the serialization problem.  The answer to the original question however is this one.

Answer (score 3):

As @Alexi answered your first question, ill try the second question in the comment. Add a KnownType attribute to your note class like this:

```
[KnownType(typeof(NoteAttachment)]
public class Note
```

Comment: Absolutely right, though this answer did fix the underlying issue I was having.  Unfortunately because I didn't ask the right question, the points have to go to @AlexiLevenkov.  Thanks!